# Iterate JavaPairRDD - return based on some condition

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a JavaPaidRDD, which i am trying to iterate and return elements based on some condition, not for all the records in the JavaPaidRDD.

Please see the below code what i am trying to achieve.

I dont want to return if the Optional has any elements Present[`if(_22.isPresent())`]. But i am not able to use `continue` there.

Is there any other we can do it, can we able to use `reduceBy` to achieve this?

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<Model, Optional<Model>>> leftOuterJoin = cfRDD.leftOuterJoin(mfRDD);
JavaRDD<Model> map = leftOuterJoin.map(tuple -> {
    Tuple2<Model, Optional<Model>> _2 = tuple._2();
        Model _1 = _2._1();
        Optional<Model> _22 = _2._2();
        if(_22.isPresent()) {
            //do not return anything
            //continue;
        }
        return _1;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you are looking for is a `flatMap`, in that case you would inside of the function instead of trying to use continue return an empty list and if you do want to return the value simply return an iterator with that value inside of it. Spark will then produce an RDD of the values and all of the ones where your condition didn't hold will not be part of the result. Another option would be to `filter` the input before mapping over it, so only the elements that pass your condition need be mapped over.

Comment: Thanks @Holden can you please give some code example for `filter` considering the above scenario..

Comment: Thanks @Holden, i got it.. i used `filter` to make it work.